# Android Phone Flip cover dismissing reminders automatically

Tags: android, alarm

I am working on a small reminder app with Alarm feature. Upon set alarm time, the reminder goes off and showing an full screen activity even if the phone is in sleep mode. This seems working perfectly.

But, if the phone is having Magnetic flip cover closed, when the fired reminder goes off, the displayed full screen activity is finishing quickly without any user interaction, which leads my application useless for phones with Magnetic flip cover.

I don't know where to look for this issue. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: So, I couldn't.